# Error about the IDENTITY_INSERT on ASP.NET API when inserting data

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

When I trying to add a row in my database, I'm catching this error :

```
IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Below the context :

I've created a Table named Tax with one primary key of two columns on SQL Server.

and I'm trying to insert this JSON for example :

```
{
  "rate":5.5,
  "name": "aCoolName55"
}
```

Tax : (Id - int / Rate - decimal(18,2) / Name - varchar(..) / State - varchar(..))

| Id | Rate | Name | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

The primary key : Id, Rate.

I did set on SQL Server Id and Rate as Primary keys. Only Id is an `IDENTITY`.

And on the .NET side, I uses the configuration file of my database context as usually.

My Data Class :

```
public class Tax
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

My class database context :

```
public class myContext: DbContext
{
           
     public myContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options)
     {

     }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       (......)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tax>().HasKey(k => new { k.Rate });
         base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

    public DbSet<Tax> Tax { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: `.HasKey(k => new { k.Id, k.Rate });` and annotate Id with database generated.

Comment: I already tried it, still not work. ```Rate``` is set as primary key and an non-identity in SQL Server, but when I'm trying to send data (I updated my post with a model example), I cannot do it because of Rate column.

Comment: The error is not about your Rate column. EF is trying to insert Id with 0.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have configured Id column as an ```identity``` with auto increment of 1.

Comment: But for the third time, you haven't told Entity Framework about that. You need `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Alright it works, thanks. but if why for other case with a primary key of a single column ```Id```, same table configuration Id as Identity, i didn't need to specify with that annotation or even adding something in the OnModelCreating builder ? And thank you again.

Comment: That's because of conventions, but as soon as you derive from those (for example using `.HasKey()`), you need to tell EF exactly what the entity looks like. :)

Comment: I am curious. Why would you make a primary key composed of an identity and a rate? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @JuanR Missconception by my fault. I realised that 2 hours ago. Good remark though Sir. Instead, I have created a primary key composed of Rate and a Foreign Key from another table.

Comment: @harili that's even **worse**. Based on your design, it seems possible for the same rate to exist more than once.

Comment: @JuanR Well, the point is to make a Rate unique for a specify UserId for example. So a User can't have the same Rate.

Comment: @harili so the `Id` column is really a `UserId` column? If that is the case, then a unique rate sounds more like a business logic concern than a data structure one and you'll probably be querying this table based on the `UserId` in order to get the rate so it would make sense for the user id to be the key... but that is mostly a philosophical discussion.

Comment: Yes it's the case @JuanR, I did just turn off the identity state of this column because I will use it to store UserId. Ahah you have another opinion of the way to do this Sir ? Tell me

Comment: @harili ha, I saw that one coming. It is my opinion that your code should be enforcing the rule that no two users can have the same rate, not your data store. What if tomorrow the business decides it's OK for two users to have the same rate? Now you'll have to go changing your data store for a business logic requirement.